# Why do I get a Apache seg fault when I using a DB singleton with a $factory

Tags: php, linux, apache, pdo, unixodbc

Why do I get a Apache seg fault when I use the $factory and how can I fix it?

I'm running the code from Linux web servers (Ubuntu and CentOS) using PHP7 with unixODBC, FreeTDS, and DBLib as the driver. I've been using the DB class below and it has been working fine...

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $factory;
    private $database;

    public static function getFactory() {
        // if (!self::$factory) {
        if (!static::$factory) {
            static::$factory = new DB();
        }
        return static::$factory;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        if (!$this->database) {
            try {
                $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->database = new PDO('dblib:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME;port=3306;charset=utf8', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', $options);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Error code: ' . $e->getCode();
                exit;
            }
        }
        return $this->database;
    }
}// end of class
?>
```

The following query runs without issue...

```
<?php
$db = DB::getFactory()->getConnection();
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".Config::get('TBL_PREFIX')."resourceTypes (name) VALUES (:name)";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':name' => $name));
die('query complete.');
?>
```

However, when I decided to use PDO's beginTransaction(), the query below fails and Apache throws a seg fault ([core:notice] [pid 1219] AH00051: child pid 31779 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2). Below is the code with the beginTransaction()...

```
<?php
$db = DB::getFactory()->getConnection();
$db->beginTransaction();// Start our transaction.
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".Config::get('TBL_PREFIX')."sched_resourceTypes (name) VALUES (:name)";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':name' => $name));
    $db->commit();// No exception, so commit the changes.
    die('committed...');
} catch(Exception $e){// Handle any exceptions that are thrown.
    echo $e->getMessage();// Print out the error message.
    $db->rollBack();// Rollback the transaction.
    die('rolling back...');
}
?>
```

If I modify my DB class to look like the following code, the above query will work without the a seg fault.

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $database;

    public static function getConnection() {
        if (!Self::$database) {
            try {
                $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                Self::$database = new PDO('dblib:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME;port=3306;charset=utf8', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', $options);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Error code: ' . $e->getCode();
                exit;
            }
        }
        return Self::$database;
    }
}// End of class
?>
```

What is the issue?

Why does the factory create a seg fault in Apache?

And most importantly, how can I correct this in the proper way?

Comment: Check returned value of `$db->beginTransaction()` is it true or false?

Comment: I can't get a returned value, the seg fault happens as soon as its called.

Comment: File a bug report with Apache?